# question on haml rendering

Tags: haml

I seem to be having a problem with haml. Rails is rendering:

```
%span
  stuff
  #div_name
  moar stuff
```

as

```
<span>stuff</span>
<div id='div_name'></div>
moar stuff
```

any ideas? why isn't 'moar stuff' inside the span?

Comment: It seems to be working for me as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
$ echo '%span\n  stuff\n  #div_name\n  moar stuff' | haml

<span>
  stuff
  <div id='div_name'></div>
  moar stuff
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%span
  stuff
#div_name
moar stuff
```

The span only contains `stuff`, so you have to undent after `stuff`, so that other elements are not contained in the span.

You can also write it like this:

```
%span stuff
#div_name
moar stuff
```

Which gives exactly this:

```
<span>stuff</span>
<div id='div_name'></div>
moar stuff
```